# xamarin C#: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Id'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently started working with Xamarin to build Android apps in C#.
There is one issue I have had in particular that makes it very hard for me to make any progress:
[error CS0117](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG0qO.png)

I have two identical projects, the issue only shows up in one of them.
It originally occured in both but rebuilding a few times fixed the first one.
The second one seems to be more persistent.
I really need to find a solution to this issue, as referencing is very basic and needed. Not to mention, it happens in every new project.
Here is my code:
[NoteMath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDsOt.png)

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace NoteMath_v1._0._1
{
    [Activity(Label = "noteMath", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Window.RequestFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            EditText etInput = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etInput);
            TextView tvConsole = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvConsole);
            etInput.KeyPress += (object sender, EditText.KeyEventArgs e) =>
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                if (e.Event.Action == Android.Views.KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Android.Views.Keycode.Enter)
                {
                    tvConsole.Append("\n>" + HandleInput.TransferInput(etInput.Text));
                    etInput.Text = "";
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post code and not pictures: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6400526)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Code added.

Comment: This usually happens when your axml-files contains an error. In that case, the `Resources.designer.cs` file can't be generated properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you posted looks good. The error is clearly not coming from there. You´ve got something wrong in any of your resource layout or xml files.

The problem actually is that Visual Studio won´t show up Resource generation errors in the Errors panel, eventhough it should be like that (I think this will be fixed in future versions). At the moment it is just telling you that the class `Id` doesn´t exists.

`Resources.designer.cs` is a class generated by Xamarin when you edit any resource file. It containts references to any declaration, id, etc in the xml/axml files. If the resource has an error, `Resources.designer.cs` generation will fail, but you get a really vague error hint.

The first thing you can try is **rebuilding your Android project**, forcing all resources to be generated again. Otherwise try the following:

Good news is that you can see generation errors by changing build output verbosity to "detailed":

[image]
[image]

Now compile your project again and check the output window. It will tell you exactly what the problem is.

After you fix it, `Resource.Id` class will be generated.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I had the issue for all new projects I created. In the end, I reinstalled xamarin and the issue was solved.

Comment: That´s probably because you installed a newer version with the bug fixed :)

Comment: I can't believe I still face this issue over and over

Comment: I still had this error even after doing this.  The only thing that worked was running the powershell script so I could see the issues with my xml files.  Still +1 because you helped get me to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked:

Step 1. 
Project > Update NugetPackages

Step 2.
Build > Clean All

Step 3. 
Build > Build All

Answer (score 1):

I am super new.  The only thing that really worked for me was manually running this powershell script in my project root:

`Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }`

I am not sure why the live view/build output isn't more helpful, or that visual studio isn't cleaning these files correctly in my xamarin project.

Special thanks to this guy:

https://montemagno.com/easily-clean-bin-obj-folders/